# How to get a file path of a folder Shift-dragged onto a pinned icon in Windows 7 using C++/WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, drag-and-drop, taskbar

Say, if I pin my app on a taskbar in Windows 7 and then shift-drag a file into its icon (the mouse changes into "Open with" prompt) and then if I release the file, it is opened with my app -- the file path is provided in the command line for the app.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get it to work if I Shift-drag a folder? In this case my app is not called although the mouse shows "Open with" as well.

PS. I'm coding using C++/MFC and WinAPIs.

Comment: It seems that it can't be done. Not even if the dragged file is a shortcut file to a folder. Pinned programs in Taskbar seem to accept only files, while pinned programs in Start Menu accept both. Normal shortcuts in Start Menu accept neither. The offline help doesn't even explain about running pinned programs by dropping file/folder on it. I don't know whether it's due to bad documentation, forgotten/disabled feature, or a bug.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad, it looked like it could be a good feature.